# How do I use the "rectangular marquee" with the "patch tool" in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, marquee-tool

In Photoshop, I want to use the patch tool but I want to select the area with a rectangular marquee instead of a lasso. How do I do this?

Google searches show how to use the marquee tool **OR** the patch tool. (sigh)

Comment: And apparently I don't have enough clout to add a 'patch-tool' tag and there isn't one already...

Comment: Why do you need an exact rectangle? The point of the Path Tool is to merge edges, doing that on a strict rectangle would merely make the rectangle *more* visible after the patch.

Answer (score 1):

- Make your selection with the Rectangle Marquee tool
- Switch to the Patch tool